# Make UINavigationItem as @IBDesignable

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem, ibdesignable

I would like to make custom `UINavigationItem`, and that changes could be made and seen in storyboard. I know how to make custom `UIView` with `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`, but my problem is that `UINavigationItem` does not have `draw` method and `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is called to soon.

How is the best approach to tackle this?

Comment: I don't think you can. `UINavigationItem` does not inherit from `UIView`. Your best chance might be to design `UINavigationBar` and views for bar button items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to make a custom `UINavigationItem` rendered in the interface builder (what `@IBDesignable` is meant for). In [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html) (a **Live Rendering** section) they say you must inherit a class from `UIView`/`NSView`. In turn, `UINavigationItem` is inherited from `NSObject`.

> Live Rendering
>
> You can use two different attributes—@IBDesignable and
>   @IBInspectable—to enable live, interactive custom view design in
>   Interface Builder. When you create a custom view that inherits from
>   the UIView class or the NSView class, you can add the @IBDesignable
>   attribute just before the class declaration. After you add the custom
>   view to Interface Builder (by setting the custom class of the view in
>   the inspector pane), Interface Builder renders your view in the
>   canvas.